# Git clone from Gitlab incredibly slow in Docker container

Tags: docker, git, gitlab

I am trying to clone our Gitlab repository into a docker container, running on a fresh VM running Ubuntu 18.04.1.

For some reason, when I try to clone the repository, I spend a long time (several minutes) looking at `Cloning into ${REPONAME}` before we finally start to enumerate objects.

```
time git clone https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls.git
Cloning into 'gnutls'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 178256, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (178256/178256), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50440/50440), done.
remote: Total 178256 (delta 128831), reused 173620 (delta 125853)
Receiving objects: 100% (178256/178256), 66.50 MiB | 10.14 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (128831/128831), done.
real    5m 2.14s
user    0m 14.42s
sys 0m 4.39s
```

I decided to try cloning a different repo, `google test` which is hosted on Github and the difference was shocking.

```
time git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
Cloning into 'googletest'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 16478 (delta 8), reused 19 (delta 8), pack-reused 16455
Receiving objects: 100% (16478/16478), 5.74 MiB | 6.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12141/12141), done.
real    0m 2.58s
user    0m 1.48s
sys 0m 0.39s
```

The Github clone is much faster than the Gitlab one!

I tested the same thing, on the VM and not inside a Docker container and the clone behaved perfectly. I am sure this must be some docker configuration thing but I have no idea where to start with it.

Comment: at least one other person is facing the same issue as me :) Did you manage to find an answer for this?

Comment: have same problem too